# Regexp different behaviours in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a set of words like this

```
"text1
"text2
"text3
```

which i need to convert to a quoted text which I was able to do with stackoverflow help like this

```
Find: ^\".*$
replace: $0"
```

There are another set of words like this

```
text1
text2
text3
```

which i need to convert to 1 quoted text which i was able to do

```
Find: ^(.+)$
Replace: "$0"
```

But in this case i was able to do it only by clicking replace all and not replace.

Can anyone tell why it's happening like this and How can I achieve this without using replace all and by using only replace?

Comment: Please leave your comments and answers here. I can respond only after a couple of hours

Comment: You match a line, since you have more than one line you have to apply the regexp for all lines: replace all.

Comment: @karthick: First off, the whole point of you asking your question is so that we can post comments as answers. There's no need for you to tell us to do that. Second, on a site like Stack Overflow it's an incredibly Bad Idea™ to post a question and disappear for the next couple of hours. If your question is unanswerable and you won't be able to respond to the input of other members, don't be surprised when you come back and find it either closed, or worse still, with no responses whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

Take care of the second replacement, it will replace `"text1"` by `""text1""`.

Use this instead:

```
find what: ^[^"\n]+$
replace: "$0"
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be working with Replace All and not Replace in any case. The function can also be affected by the position of the cursor and the direction to find/replace.

To be certain, you can place the cursor at the beginning of the file, ensure that the find direction is 'Down' and use Replace All.

Now to the regex, yes, you can do it in a single replace. Use this find:

```
^(?:")?(.*)$
```

And this replace:

```
"$1"
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/qB2rF5).

The `(?:")?` will consume the first double quote if present so that it isn't placed in the replace later on.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way you used "Replace" only once in the first case! You must have pressed it 3 times (as many as your matches).

In both situations you need "Replace all", since you want multiple global matches. When pressing the "Replace all" button it's like using [Perl's](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers) `/g` & `/m` modifiers in your substitution, you can experiment [here](http://regex101.com/r/pW3eP5) to see what I mean.

BTW the use of a capture group (the parenthesis) is redundant in your 2nd example, use find: `^.+$` and replace: `"$0"`.

Comment: No. For the first one I had to press replace only once. You can try that. I am using Notepad++ v 6.2.2

Comment: I did tried :) Probably there's a misunderstanding of what exactly you/I mean.